# Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot destructure property

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to pass die parameters in the body to a cloud function in firebase.
I get this message in the log:

> Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'request.body' as it is undefined.

dart code:

```
HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('addmessage');
final HttpsCallableResult result = await callable.call(
                          <String, dynamic>{
                            'name': "Pippo",
                            'value': "Data",
                          },
                        );
```

server code:

```
exports.addmessage = onCall({cors: true},(request) => {
  const {name,value} = request.body;
  logger.info("name: "+name);
  return "prova"+name;
});
```

how can i read the data in the body of the cloud function?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `body` from `request`, you must get it from `data`.

```
exports.someCallableFunc = onCall(async (request) => {
    const data = request.data;
    const someString = data.someString;
    ...
});
```